# Matlab input statement

Tags: function, matlab, input

Genuinely don't know how to code and I need to change this to include an input to ask for the given lengths. This is my current code:

```
    tank_Volume(2.75, 3.0, 62.3)
    % b is base length in feet, h is height in feet
    %p is rho in lb/ft^3
    %volume in ft^3, m is mass in lb
    function [m] = tank_Volume(b, h, p)
    v = (b * h)/3;
    m = p * v;
    end
```

Comment: Please include the version of your code that got when trying to change the values to the needed input statement. What error message do you get, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just asking for a front-end user interface, you can use the input( ) function:

```
b = input('Enter base length in feet ');
h = input('Enter height in feet ');
p = input('Enter rho in lb/ft^3 ');
m = tank_Volume(b,h,p);
```